# Pdfbox : Draw image in rotated page

Tags: java, draw, pdfbox

I have a simple A4 pdf document with a property `/Rotate 90` : The original version of my pdf is landscape but printed portrait.

I am trying to draw a small image at the bottom left of the portait document.

Here is my code so far :

```
    File file = new File("rotated90.pdf");
    try (final PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file)) {
        PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
        PDImageXObject image = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("image.jpg", doc);
        PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false, true);
        contents.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        contents.close();
        doc.save(new File("newpdf.pdf"));
}
```

Here is the end result : As you can see the image was placed at the top left (which was the 0,0 coordinate before rotation) and was not rotated.

[image: s]

I tried playing with `drawImage(PDImageXObject image, Matrix matrix)` without success.

Here is the orignal document [pdf with 90° rotation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oja_MYUh6z9kq4YS2dwnxOybRN-_eJ5q/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution for a page that is rotated 90°:

```
PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
PDImageXObject image = ....
cs.saveGraphicsState();
cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90), page.getCropBox().getWidth() + page.getCropBox().getLowerLeftX(), 0));
cs.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
cs.restoreGraphicsState();
cs.close();
```

If it is only the image, then you don't need the save/restore.

Solution for a page that is rotated 270°:

```
cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(270), 0, page.getCropBox().getHeight() + page.getCropBox().getLowerLeftY()));
```

For 180°:

```
cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(180), page.getCropBox().getWidth() + page.getCropBox().getLowerLeftX(), page.getCropBox().getHeight() + page.getCropBox().getLowerLeftY()));
```

Comment: Looks good if the PDF indeed has a crop box with the origin in its unrotated lower left corner.

Comment: Thank you, I wished that pdfbox provides a more direct way than rotating back the page. But in the end it works.

Comment: Only 180 working. For 90, I just change getWidth to getHeight then it start working. For 270, it still not working.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I tested it when I wrote this. Maybe there is something different with your document.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hCWFVyHqFEXA5ZRbVBP_RGD13x5I6OAW?usp=share_link @TilmanHausherr I am using these documents. `cs.drawImage(image,56,661,212,70);`

Comment: Works exactly as described (with a PNG file from me). Please add the image too, maybe there's confusion there. Some JPEG files from mobile devices have a builtin rotation.