# Pdfbox : Draw image in rotated page by 270 degree

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have to draw an image on the rotated page by 270 degree.
So far I have taken reference from below reference. (Just for your information, I have to position the image on either corner of the page i.e. BOTTOM RIGHT, BOTTOM LEFT, TOP RIGHT and TOP LEFT.)

[Reference to draw an image on the page rotation of 90 degree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597316/pdfbox-draw-image-in-rotated-page?rq=1)

Here's a solution for 90° provided by @Tilman Hausherr,

```java
PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
PDImageXObject image = ....
cs.saveGraphicsState();
cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90), page.getCropBox().getWidth() + page.getCropBox().getLowerLeftX(), 0));
cs.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
cs.restoreGraphicsState();
cs.close();
```

Please tell me that what changes I should incorporate to make that code work for 270 degree page rotation as well.

**My working code for 90 degree rotation:**

```
PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(getSourceFilePath()), "");
    int total = pdDocument.getNumberOfPages();
    
    PDPage page = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
    PDRectangle rectangle = getRotatedMediaBox(page);
    
    PDDocument newDocument = new PDDocument();
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        PDPage pdPage = newDocument.importPage(pdDocument.getPage(i));
        PDRectangle pageRect = getRotatedMediaBox(pdPage);
        
        int rotation = pdPage.getRotation();            
        
        PDRectangle cropBoxRect =  page.getCropBox(); 
        
        //Calculate margin between crop box rectangle and page rectangle.
        float[] margins = getCropBoxMargin(pageRect, cropBoxRect, rotation);
        
        if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270) {
            cropBoxRect = new PDRectangle(cropBoxRect.getLowerLeftY(), cropBoxRect.getLowerLeftX(), cropBoxRect.getHeight(),
                    cropBoxRect.getWidth());
        }
        
        float width = cropBoxRect.getWidth();
        float height = cropBoxRect.getHeight();
        
        ABarcodeDisplacementVO displacementVO = aBarcodeVO.getDisplacementVO();
        displacementVO.setPageWidth(width);
        displacementVO.setPageHeight(height);
        
        //Calculate llx and lly for QR Code image.
        float rectLlx = getOffsetX(displacementVO, qrImageSize) + margins[0];
        float rectLly = getOffsetY(displacementVO, qrImageSize) + margins[1];
        
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = getImage();
        PDPageContentStream pageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(newDocument, pdPage,
                PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
        PDImageXObject image = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(newDocument, bufferedImage);
         
        if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270) {
            pageContentStream.saveGraphicsState();
            pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(rotation), pdPage.getCropBox().getWidth() + pdPage.getCropBox().getLowerLeftX(), 0));
        }
        
        pageContentStream.drawImage(image, rectLlx, rectLly, qrImageSize, qrImageSize);
        pageContentStream.restoreGraphicsState();
        pageContentStream.close();
    }
newDocument.save(new File(getDestinationFilePath(false)));
newDocument.close();
pdDocument.close();
```

Comment: Try changing the 90 in *Math.toRadians(90)* to either 270 or -90.  There are 360 degrees in a circle.

Comment: Additionally you have to change the translation coordinates of the `getRotateInstance` because your changed rotation rotates the image position to be into y different quadrant.

Comment: Thanks you guys for response. As per suggestion I have tried changing y position but it has not helped. It would be great help if you suggest code changes if I'm mistaken somewhere. I have added my working code for 90 degree rotation.

Comment: [Pdfbox : Draw image in rotated page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597316/pdfbox-draw-image-in-rotated-page) I've updated it for 270° :-)

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Thanks guys for your constant support since I have started my journey in PDFBox. I could manage to learn lot from the provided solutions.